# Moving Steam to an external hard drive. Unplugged during transfer

Tags: steam

I started to move my Steam account and my games to an external hard drive and it got unplugged during the transfer.  Now the hard drive has a few of the start-up apps on it but I can still play my games from my computer.

Do I restart the transfer as is or do I wipe the external drive first?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming Windows 10. Your files only are *deleted* from the source when the move procedure is finished. So, wipe external HDD, and restart.

If you don't wipe the external HDD, you'll be prompted to overwrite. Chose yes to everything, and it should work as well. Just make sure you chose yes when overwriting, since one of those files is definitely corrupted since the transfer was interrupted.